# How to use operator.itemgetter to check a condition in a filter function instead of a lambda?

Tags: python

Say, I have a list of tuples like so

```
tupleSet=[(0, 2), (3, 4), (5, 7)]
```

I want to get another list of tuples satisfying the condition where the second element of the tuple is an even number.

```
>>> [(0, 2), (3, 4)]
```

I am wondering if this can be done using the itemgetter in the filter function.

I know a lambda can be used

```
list(filter(lambda x: not x[1]%2,tupleSet))
```

I want an equivalent code (one-liner) using the operator.itemgetter, if at all it is possible.

I tried using

```
list(filter(operator.itemgetter(1)%2==0,tupleSet))
```

but I get this

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'operator.itemgetter' and 'int'
```

Required Output :

```
[(0, 2), (3, 4)]
```

using the itemgetter function

Comment: You missed to pass your variable to itemgetter. Try `list(filter(operator.itemgetter(1)(tupleSet)%2==0,tupleSet))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `itemgetter()`, but not without using a `lambda` (or the `def functionname(): ...` statement syntax to define a callable, or other compositions of objects).

The first argument to `filter()` **must** be a callable object. While `operator.itemgetter(1)`, on its own, is such an object and can be used in `filter()`, the expression `operator.itemgetter(1)%2==0` doesn't work because you can't just use the `%` operator on `itemgetter()` objects and so raises a `TypeError`. Even if it didn't do that, you'd be passing the *outcome* of the `operator.itemgetter(1)%2==0` expression to `filter()`, so it'd be called once, before `filter()` runs, and that's not what you want either.

The `lambda` you passed in, `lambda x: not x[1]%2`, is also a callable object, namely a function. It works because the `lambda <args>: <expression>` syntax doesn't immediately call the `<expression>` part, but instead returns a function object, so a callable object. The expression contained in the function (`not x[1]%2`), is executed only when the function is *called* (so, by `filter()` for each element).

A different way of spelling the same thing would use a `def` statement to create a named function first:

```
def second_element_is_even(tup):
    return not tup[1] % 2

list(filter(second_element_is_even, tupleSet))
```

That's exactly the same thing as the version with `lambda`, except now the function object is available under the name `second_element_is_even` too.

If you must use an `itemgetter()` object, then you would have to write a different callable that then called for each filtered item, and uses the `itemgetter()` object as a tool to produce the desired filtering decision. Like a `lambda`:

```
get_second = operator.itemgetter(1)
list(filter(lambda x: not get_second(x) % 2, tupleSet))
```

That's not very useful, as `x[1]` is really a lot more readable.

However, if you ever needed for the specific element to be *variable* (sometimes it has to be the first, sometimes the second element of the tuple, sometimes it should be the sum), then an `itemgetter` object could be used to codify this. You can produce a *element is even* function that accepts a *key* to figure out what it should test:

```
def even_tester(key=None):
    if key is None:
        # identity function, test the value directly
        key = lambda v: v
    def is_even(value):
        return not key(value) % 2
    return is_even

# test if the second element is even
list(filter(even_tester(operator.itemgetter(1)), tupleSet))

# test if the first element is even
list(filter(even_tester(operator.itemgetter(1)), tupleSet))

# test if the sum of the elements is even
list(filter(even_tester(sum), tupleSet))
```

`even_tester()` here works a lot like `itemgetter()`: calling it gives you a new object that itself can be called too. What it does when called is determined by the argument you pass to `even_tester()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer: this answer only serves as a curiosity; the correct method is still to use `lambda`s.

For this particular case there is a rather convoluted way to avoid `lambda`s:

```
# imports
import operator as op, itertools as it
```

1. Fetch the second element from each tuple and `zip` them with 2:

   ```
   >>> a = zip(map(op.itemgetter(1), tupleSet), it.repeat(2, len(tupleSet)))
   >>> list(a)
   [(2, 2), (4, 2), (7, 2)]
   ```
2. Using `itertools.starmap`, call `operator.mod` with each of these tuples as arguments:

   ```
   >>> b = it.starmap(op.mod, a)
   >>> list(b)
   [0, 0, 1]
   ```
3. Check for even numbers in a similar way:

   ```
   >>> c = it.starmap(op.eq, zip(b, it.repeat(0, len(tupleSet))))
   >>> list(c)
   [True, True, False]
   ```
4. `zip` with the original array, `filter` by these boolean flags, and extract the desired results with `itemgetter`:

   ```
   >>> d = map(op.itemgetter(1), filter(op.itemgetter(0), zip(c, tupleSet)))
   >>> list(d)
   [(0, 2), (3, 4)]
   ```

Combining these parts creates a horrible mess:

```
list(map(op.itemgetter(1), filter(op.itemgetter(0), zip(it.starmap(op.eq, zip(it.starmap(op.mod, zip(map(op.itemgetter(1), tupleSet), it.repeat(2, len(tupleSet)))), it.repeat(0, len(tupleSet)))), tupleSet))))
```

Although the above stays true to the original intent, it is in no way as efficient or readable as the "canonical" solution with `lambda`s.

Answer (score 0):

### The one-liner using `itemgetter` in the `filter` function

Taking into account that `filter` takes an iterable and `itemgetter(n)` the nth element of an iterable, you will need an iterable of iterables such that their nth elements were the truth values of your proposition.

Taking advantage of the fact that `x % 2` self-assess its oddness we can easily build an iterable that satisfies the condition:

```py
(not y % 2 for x, y in t)
```

We only need to link that truth values to their variables to get the *iterable of iterables*:

```py
((not y % 2, (x, y)) for x, y in t)
```

Now we can get the filtered list with `filter` and `itemgetter`:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

s = filter(itemgetter(0), ((not y % 2, (x, y)) for x, y in l))
```

And finally, to getting rid of the truth values:

```py
>>> _, s = zip(*filter(itemgetter(0), ((not y % 2, (x, y)) for x, y in t)))
>>> s
((0, 2), (3, 4))
```

It's not a R'lyehian sounding Perl-esque one-liner, but it's not a best practise example either.

---

### A functional alternative

In addition to `filter -> lambda` solutions, there's a built-in function specially designed to filter an iterable in base of the truth values of a second iterable: `itertools.compress`. The previous filtering can be made like:

```py
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> list(compress(t, (not y % 2 for x, y in t))) 
[(0, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Which is a more concise one-liner both in the functional part and in the list comprehension.

---

### A Pythonic alternative

```
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in t if not y % 2]
[(0, 2), (3, 4)]
```

And that's all. As explained in:

```
>>> import this
```

;)